# How to make a transfer from nodejs (using EOS)?

Tags: cleos

I have code working with Ethereum using nodejs and a send transaction. Is there an equivalent using eos? The basic task under ethereum is that A pays B with the server.js file making the transfer and the keys are stored in an .env variable, then web3 enables the txn.

The key line is in ethereum -

```
  web3js.eth.sendRawTransaction
```

I assume eos has some kind of equivalent payment? Any tips are welcome.

Here is my ethereum code (testnet) -

```
app.post("/api/makePayment",function(req,res){

   var payAmount = req.body.payAmount; //n//
   var payeeAccount = req.body.payeeAccount;  //n
   var freqPayment = req.body.freqPayment; //n

   var myAddress = "0xd3a20af365538c2090f7b81496a83365c2489b3b";

  localContractABI= [ { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "payeeWallet", "type": "address" } ], "name": "addPayeeWalle
t", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ 
{ "name": "payeeWallet", "type": "address" } ], "name": "payWallet", "outputs": [ { "name": "success", "type": "bool" } ], "p
ayable": true, "stateMutability": "payable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonp
ayable", "type": "constructor" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "owner", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "addr
ess" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "name": "", "t
ype": "address" } ], "name": "PayeeWallets", "outputs": [ { "name": "PayeeAllowed", "type": "bool" } ], "payable": false, "st
ateMutability": "view", "type": "function" } ]

   localContractAddress="0xe28497515f9a57b16b92102eaa0b407f7f20d6d4";

   //var infuraApiKey =process.env.INFURA_API_KEY;
  // var privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;

   var web3js = new web3(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://178.128.172.167:8501"));

   web3js.eth.defaultAccount = myAddress;
   var privateKey=new Buffer(process.env.PAYMENT_PRIVATE_KEY, 'hex');

//   var toAddress = 'ADRESS_TO_SEND_TRANSACTION';

   //contract abi is the array that you can get from the ethereum wallet or etherscan
   var contractABI =localContractABI;
   var contractAddress =localContractAddress;
   //creating contract object
   var contract =  web3js.eth.contract(contractABI).at(contractAddress);
   var count;
   var nounce;
   var errcode="";

//   var apiKeyHash = web3js.sha3(authKey);

   var chainId = 1515;

   web3js.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress, function(err, result) {
      nounce=result;
      var nounceHex = web3js.toHex(nounce);
      var rawTransaction = {
      "from":myAddress,
      "gasPrice":web3js.toHex(2*1e9),
      "gasLimit":web3js.toHex(90000),
      "to":payeeAccount,
      "value": web3js.toHex(web3js.toWei(payAmount, 'wei')), // must be in hex
      "chainId": web3js.toHex(chainId), // must be in hex
    //  "data":contract.payWallet.getData(payeeAccount),
      "nonce":nounceHex}

      var transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction);
      transaction.sign(privateKey);

      var serializedTx = transaction.serialize();
      web3js.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x'+serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err1, hash) {
          if (!err1) {
             res.json({ message:hash});
          } else res.json({ message:err1});
      }); // raw
   }) //get

});
```

Comment: Did you check out [eosjs](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs)?

Comment: How is the permission handled? They have an example there - but what where is the key stored? It just says "active" under permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I implemented eosjs in a NodeJS application. Node package used: `"eosjs": "^16.0.6"`:

[Link to version of my repo with this](https://github.com/NatPDeveloper/eos-chess/blob/ece9a740c27ff3f09f31ee2e52b34faf740bd639/app.js)

```
const Eos = require('eosjs');
config = {
    chainId: 'cf057bbfb72640471fd910bcb67639c22df9f92470936cddc1ade0e2f2e7dc4f', // 32 byte (64 char) hex string
    keyProvider: ['PRIVATE_KEY_HERE'], // WIF string or array of keys..
    httpEndpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888',
    authorization: 'test@active'
};

const eos = Eos(config);
eos.contract('eosio', (error, eosio) => { // or .then(
    console.log(Object.keys(eosio))
    eosio.getplayer('test') //specifying action
})
```

I also have an example of integrating Scatter in the same application to handle keys:
https://github.com/NatPDeveloper/eos-chess/blob/master/js/lib/scatter-js/scatter.js

---

I used eosjs's legacy docs for this which you can find here:

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/tree/v16.0.9

Here, you hard code your private key.  You could also store it in a .env file.  If you want your contract to sign a transaction itself, you will need to add the eosio.code permission level to your account, more on this [in the docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/inline-actions)

```
Eos = require('eosjs')

// Default configuration
config = {
  chainId: null, // 32 byte (64 char) hex string
  keyProvider: ['PrivateKeys...'], // WIF string or array of keys..
  httpEndpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888',
  expireInSeconds: 60,
  broadcast: true,
  verbose: false, // API activity
  sign: true
}

eos = Eos(config)

eos.transfer('alice', 'bob', '1.0000 SYS', '', options)
```

---

Adding @active per your comment:

> If a keyProvider is not provided here, one may be provided on a
>   per-action or per-transaction basis in Options.

```
options = {
  authorization: 'alice@active',
  broadcast: true,
  sign: true
}

eos.transfer('alice', 'bob', '1.0000 SYS', '', options)
```

- > `authorization [array<auth>|auth]` - identifies the signing account and
  >   permission typically in a multisig configuration. Authorization may be
  >   a string formatted as account@permission or an object<{actor: account,
  >   permission}>.

> - If missing default authorizations will be calculated.
> - If provided additional authorizations will not be added.
> - Performs deterministicsorting by account name
>
> If a default authorization is calculated the
>   action's 1st field must be an account_name. The account_name in the
>   1st field gets added as the active key authorization for the action.

- > `broadcast [boolean=true]` - post the transaction to the blockchain. Use
  >   false to obtain a fully signed transaction.
- > `sign [boolean=true]` - sign the transaction with a private key. Leaving
  >   a transaction unsigned avoids the need to provide a private key.
- > `keyProvider [array<string>|string|function]` - just like the global
  >   keyProvider except this provides a temporary key for a single action
  >   or transaction.

`await eos.anyAction('args', {keyProvider})`

`await eos.transaction(tr => { tr.anyAction() }, {keyProvider})`

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/tree/v16.0.9#options

Comment: worked but I needed to add this in config -   authorization: 'john11@active' - john11 is the account in eos.

Comment: I've added more to my answer.  If a key provider is not given, you can pass options which will allow you to specify the permission as you outlined.

Comment: I had some permission errors even when the key was given and the auth line solved it.